# mIRC .txt timer based script

Tags: mirc

trying to make a timer delayed based script for mIRC for a scenario based game. everything is put together  and should run but when I actually go to start the script it just says unknown command.

```
SCRIPT {  
  /TIMER1 1 1 /query #mircroom THIS IS WHAT I WANT IT TO SAY  
  /TIMER2 1 4 /query #mircroom2 THIS IS WHAT I WANT IT TO SAY  
}
```

I put it into alias's so in theory I should just have to type /SCRIPT and it would run right? I also threw it into it's own .txt file and it did not recognize starting the script.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using /msg instead of /query. /query generally works with nicknames

Answer (score 0):

`$script` is a [built-in identifier](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/identifiers/$script)

> $script can be used to return the filename of the Nth loaded script file. If you specify a filename, it returns $null if the file is not loaded; otherwise it returns the file's name.

Try to give it another name and it should work

Comment: So if I just said test and put it in alias and said /test it should work?

Comment: didn't work, Gave it a shot need to figure out how to get this to run.

Comment: Unknown command changing it to msg instead of query didn't return any of the injected messages to the proper rooms

Comment: It works fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/oqQTKQr.png, so I guess you're missing a bracket somewhere above the file